# When the owner of a Realm is not on the Realm, can players join it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I am planning on creating a Minecraft Realm on Bedrock Edition. However, I want it to be like a server, so players can join whenever they want, even if the owner is not online. Can players join a Realm when the owner is not online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [MCBE help article](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035061331-How-do-I-invite-people-to-my-Realm-):

> Invite links are custom URLs, unique to your Realm, that you can use to invite new members. When someone clicks on an invite link, they will be prompted to sign in or sign up with their Xbox Live account, then immediately added to the Realm’s whitelist. That means they can jump into the world right away – even if the owner isn’t online.

I'm assuming that this will be applied to players specifically invited as well as those from invite links. If my assumption is correct, you can most certainly join without the owner being online.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. If the owner doesn't play for a few days, the realm will disappear until the owner logs back on. It's very frustrating for everyone.